# React pass state between components and pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, state

I am new to React and very amateur with js. I am having an issue with passing state around components. I have a component that is a button in a separate file. When the user clicks it, they get prompted to do some stuff from a 3rd party and I get back some things(information) like an acct number.

I want to pass that acct number back to app.js and then to other components and pages so that I can change behavior based on it.
Below is the code for reference:

app.js

```
function App() {
    const [mmAccount, setMMAccount] = useState('');

    function handleChildClick(mmAccount) {
        setMMAccount(mmAccount)
        console.log('new acct:', mmAccount);
}


  return (
    <Router>
   
    <SpecialButton mmAccount={mmAccount} onAcctChange={handleChildClick}/>
```

specialbutton.js

```
function SpecialButton({ mmAccount, onAcctChange }) {
    
    const { activate, deactivate, account } = imported3rdpartystuff()   

    function handleClick(event) {
    onAcctChange(event.target.account)
    console.log("handle click", mmAccount); 
  }

   if (window.somestuff is true) {
    return [  <p> {!account && <LoadingButton
   } />} onClick={(e) => { activate(); handleClick(e)}}> Connect Here</LoadingButton>}
      {account && <Button
      variant="contained" />}
      onClick={deactivate}>Disconnect: {account.substring(0,5)} ... {account.slice(-4)} </Button>}</p>,
    ];}
```

I feel like event.target.account is not the way to get the value of account into mmAccount and pass back up to app.js. I've tried maybe 5 different variations of functions and constants. Now, trying explicitly to pass account to this event.target syntax,I don't really understand.

If I pass account directly, I get the following error:

```
function handleClick(event) {
    onAcctChange(account)
```

and console.log(mmAccount) in either app.js or the button file, I get value as undefined.

Is the update running before mmAccount gets updated or anyone have another idea of where I went wrong?

Comment: Skimming through the code, this looks like roughly the correct strategy to bubble the data up to the page. Is there a specific bug you're encountering rather than just "I feel like event.target.account is not the way"? Like is the data reaching the parent just undefined, or is it not reaching it at all, etc.?

Comment: thanks, glad to hear im on the right track. When I console.log(mmAccount) i dont get anything. 

But I can console.log(account) and see its getting a value. So seems its not actually passing the value back up to the parent